# Browser keeps changing print page size

Tags: google-chrome, browser, printing

I have set in browser paper size to be 30mm wide and 20mm height. but when I click print the preview is showing and it is 20mm wide and 30 mm height. after printing I find the preview printed. The printer I am using Xprinter 370B. why is it? I have tried everything I could think of, and also tried different browsers all the same.

here is the link to the page I am trying to print.
http://turonstroy.uz/admin/print_label_solo.php